# I'm not able to convert my python file into a exe using pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, exe, pyinstaller

[The Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utIGK.png)

I'm getting this error Everytime I try to convert a python file into exe file using pyinstaller.
The command I use is - **pyinstaller filename.py**

Comment: I believe this is a known issue with pyinstaller and python 3.8. A direct install via pip should help: `pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.tar.gz`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python version 3.8, pyinstaller doesn't work. If a direct install via pip doesn't help, try downgrading to python version 3.7.